# Where to find list of deprecated settings for nova? Juno

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Here is the scheduler_default_filters setting I am using my /etc/nova/nova.conf.  I think some of these settings are obsolete/deprecated in Juno ...

```
scheduler_default_filters = AggregateInstanceExtraSpecsFilter,AvailabilityZoneFilter,RamFilter,ComputeFilter,CoreFilter,DifferentHostFilter,SameHostFilter,GroupAntiAffinityFilter,AggregateCoreFilter,AggregateRamFilter,AggregateTypeAffinityFilter
```

... but I am not sure where to find the definitive listing of current and deprecated nova settings.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Juno documentation here: http://docs.openstack.org/juno/config-reference/content/section_compute-scheduler.html

Each of the filters is listed and if one is deprecated it will say so like:

http://docs.openstack.org/juno/config-reference/content/section_compute-scheduler.html#groupaffinityfilter